# how to store a chicken sandwich overnight for lunch the next day

Tags: storage-method, sandwich

I am currently preparing a chicken breast sandwich using this [recipe.](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/food-network-kitchens/chicken-roasted-pepper-and-pesto-sandwich-recipe.html) However, this is for consumption tomorrow on campus. What's the best way to store this and have it for lunch tomorrow? I only have a microwave so I am thinking if I put it in the fridge and reheat it, it will get extremely soggy.

How do I store it so that the chicken retains its juices and tenderness (and that the bun/sauces) don't make it super soggy.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally wait with assembling it until right before eating. Put the bread in a bag, the sliced chicken in a bag, and find a small container to keep the pesto in. Then you can assemble and heat on "grill" for a minute or so when you're ready to eat it. That should prevent any sogginess.

Comment: Would probably be safe to mingle the chicken and pesto, just keep bread separate

Comment: @zerobane, absolutely.